# Can one generate a grid of the Locales where a Distribution is mapped?

Tags: chapel

If I run the following code:

```
use BlockDist;
config const dimension: int = 5;
const space = {0..#dimension, 0..#dimension};
const matrixBlock: domain(2) dmapped Block(boundingBox=space) = space;
var A : [matrixBlock] int;
[a in A] a = a.locale.id;
writeln(A);
```

on 4 Locales, I get:

```
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
2 2 2 3 3
2 2 2 3 3
```

Is there a `A.<function>` which returns the matrix (below)?

```
0 1
2 3
```

Or, is this something I should implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `A.targetLocales()` gives you almost what you asked for, and maybe something you'll find even more useful: Rather than the array of `int`s you requested, it gives you an array of the target locales themselves.  Thus, `writeln(A.targetLocales())` prints the 2x2 locale array:

```
LOCALE0 LOCALE1
LOCALE2 LOCALE3
```

This routine, and others related to locality queries on arrays, can be found in the [domain and array operations](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.array) section of the online documentation, under the array type.

The expression `A.targetLocales().id` *ought* to give you what you want, but due to a [longstanding unimplemented feature](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/5958) does not (at least, as of version 1.15 of Chapel).  In short, this asks each locale for its ID and *should* result in an array of ints with the same size and shape as the target locales array; yet because promotion doesn't preserve shape as intended, the shape is lost if you don't preserve it.  For example, `writeln(A.targetLocales.id)` results in:

```
0 1 2 3
```

rather than:

```
0 1
2 3
```

However, you can assign such promoted expressions into an array of the desired shape.  So one way to get your desired array of ints today would be to write:

```
// declare an array whose domain is the same as that of A's target locales
// and initialize the array using the IDs of A's targetLocales array:
var IDs: [A.targetLocales().domain] int = A.targetLocales().id;
```

Finally, note that you can pass your own array of locales into the Block() distribution's constructor if you wish to specify a specific target locale set, rather than using the default set of target locales that it sets up for you.  For example, adding the two following lines:

```
const locGridSpace = {0..#numLocales, 0..0};
const locGrid: [locGridSpace] locale = [(i,j) in locGridSpace] Locales[i];
```

will create a numLocales x 1 array of locales which can then be passed into your call to Block() as follows:

```
const matrixBlock: domain(2) dmapped Block(boundingBox=space, 
                                           targetLocales=locGrid) = space;
```

Alternatively, you could arrange some or all of the locales into some other shape or ordering.  The main restriction is that the rank of the targetLocales array matches that of the domains to which the distribution is applied.  (So targetLocales must be 2D when distributing 2D domains and arrays and 3D for 3D domains and arrays).

Comment: I was thinking about doing the 1-dimensional locale grid, but the algorithm I want to implement should be simpler with the 2d locale grid. It might even be faster at the end. Thanks again Brad!

Answer (score 2):

Arrays, domains, and distributions all have a `targetLocales()` method that returns the array of locales over which the array/domain/distribution is distributed.  See: [Domain and Array Operations](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html) documentation.

The following calls:

```
writeln(A.targetLocales());
writeln(A.domain.targetLocales());
writeln(A.domain.dist.targetLocales());
```

Will all print:

```
LOCALE0 LOCALE1
LOCALE2 LOCALE3
```

To extract the integral ids, you can then use the `.id` accessor:

```
var targetLocs = A.targetLocales();
var targetLocIDs: [targetLocs.domain] int = targetLocs.id;
writeln(targetLocIDs);
```

Prints:

```
0 1
2 3
```